# How to send GET Request in PHP with the client IP?

Tags: php, get

PHP:

```
<?php
$opts = array(
'http'=>array(
'method'=>"GET",
'header'=>"Referer: http://www.ucaster.me/hembedplayer/shid03/1/1/1" .
          "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:51.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/51.0"
));
$url = file_get_contents('http://www.ucaster.me/hembedplayer/shid03/1/1/1', false, stream_context_create($opts));
preg_match('/Video\("([^"]*)/', $url, $m);
header('Location: http://178.162.199.131:8088/live/shid03/playlist.m3u8?pk='.$m[1]);
```

My PHP code is stored on my VPS as WebServer,

As soon as I enter the WebServer PHP Page through my main computer the m3u8 file should work with the token (pk)

The problem is that the m3u8 token (pk) itself is GEO, it works only with the IP through which the GET Request was sent,

And the GET Request sent with the IP address of the VPS.

The solution I've done is to run a proxy server on my main computer, and add the proxy in the headers.

But I want to know if there is an alternative way, Example:

When i run the PHP page from my computer

The GET Request will send through the client IP address

(The computer through which the PHP Page opens)

Comment: You could try sending a `X-Forwarded-For` header with the client ip address and hope that ucaster takes this as the client ip.

Comment: @RolandStarke Thank you, I've done a test now through firefox and it seems to me it works. But when I will be at home I check on the PHP file also, and update

Comment: @RolandStarke its didnt work:( But I tried to make a whatmyip php page on the web server and check with it, and it does not work either. so I do not know where the problem is

Comment: Then you have bad luck. You can't change your ip to your visitor ip.